# Why vertica is not supporting identity in temp table? Any alternate solution?

Tags: putty, vertica

When i am creating a temp table with identity in vertica , its showing error message as 'cant create a temp table with identity'. Why its not supporting? I need other solution please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an identity, which is a special case of a sequence, you can explicitly create a sequence, and use it:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tstident_seq;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tstident (id INT DEFAULT NEXTVAL('tstident_seq'), value INT);
INSERT INTO tstident (value) VALUES (42);
-- to check
SELECT * FROM tstident;
```

The output is, as expected:

```
 id | value
----+-------
  1 |    42
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

create a regular table with a default projection with an identity, use it, and drop it.

Comment: Flagged up in the lqp queue.  Geoff, would you please explain what you have written?  Or otherwise provide substance?  Thanks....

Comment: I haven't done this in a while, but I have in a past. In a shell script or something like that I create a table with the structure I want. When I'm done with it, I drop it. It pretty much acts like a temp table. Not ideal, but it gets the job done.